# Как правильно определять зависимые слова в причастном или деепричастном обороте?

Tags: синтаксис

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего это делать так, как учат в школе: зависимые слова - это слова, к которым можно поставить вопрос от причастия или деепричастия и далее по цепочке (Ученик, задавший интересный вопрос: ученик, задавший (что?) вопрос (какой?) интересный). То же с деепричастным оборотом.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не совершать ошибок, внимательно следите за тем, от какого слова задается вопрос. Для примера разберите предложение:
**Девочка бежала по булыжной мостовой, радостно напевая песенку.**

Найдите деепричастие. В данном случае это слово «напевая». Теперь нужно найти зависимые слова. Задавайте вопросы: «Напевая… что? Песенку». «Напевая… как? Радостно». Значит, слова «песенку» и «радостно» будут зависимы от деепричастия, а значит, все вместе они образуют деепричастный оборот. Деепричастный оборот в предложении является обособленным обстоятельством и всегда выделяется запятыми с обеих сторон.
Это правило применимо как для деепричастных (независимо от места положения деепричастия - начало, средина или конец предложения), так и причастных оборотах, стоящих после зависимых слов. 
По-другому обстоят дела с причастным оборотом, стоящим перед определяемым словом.Его   обособлять  не следует. Например:
Расположенный напротив дома Золушки дворец построен за три месяца.
И далее по схеме: определили причастие "расположенный"... где?... напротив...чего?...дома...чьего?...Золушки.
Я думаю, что эти правила вы знаете, но бывает и так, что действительно трудно найти окончание этих самых оборотов. Если сомневаетесь, разберите по схеме или мысленно уберите  оборот из предложения - смысл не потеряется, значит, выделен был правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Если перед деепричастным оборотом стоит усилительная частица *и*, запятая не ставится:

Можно много путешествовать и не зная, в каком полушарии какая страна находится.

Деепричастные обороты не обособляются:
а)  если оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания, например: Она сидела чуть откинув голову, задумчивая и грустная (Г. Марков) (указывается не просто, что «она сидела», а «сидела с откинутой головой»); Мальчик шел прихрамывая на левую ногу, Это Упражнение делают стоя на вытянутых носках; Студенты приобретают знания не только слушая лекции, но и выполняя практические работы; Писал он обычно наклонив голову и прищурив глаз. Ср. у М. Горького: Жили Артамоновы ни с кем не знакомясь; Не унижая себя говорю, а говорю с болью в сердце; Огромного роста, редкой силы, волосатый, он ходил по земле наклоня голову, как бык; Можно прожить и не хвастая умом, без этих разговоров... Ср. в составе другой конструкции (деепричастный оборот не отделяется запятой от причастия, к которому тесно примыкает): Кучер, спавший опершись на локоть, начал пятить лошадей (Гончаров); Даже и Ласка, спавшая свернувшись кольцом в краю сена, неохотно встала (Л. Толстой);

если оборот представляет собой идиоматическое выражение,